# Display image from website in ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to display image in a `ListActivity`. I am reading the name from XML and also placing a `WebView` in my activity. Code is as below:

```
String imagename = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageText))
        .getText().toString();
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webproduct);
web.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/simage/" + imagename);
```

I am getting the image name but no image. In separate activity image is displayed from website in `WebView` but in `ListActivity` is does not.

Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Comment: Internet Permission has been also given

Comment: Have a look at this sample code https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: why you have used webview to display image from URL ? The I have given below will work better in such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a custom list adapter to display images from the server.

You can do lazy loading which increases performance as images are displayed when the view is visible.

For the lazy list you can use the sample from [this project](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). With this, the images are also cached. Once images are cached you can display the image when you have no connectivity.

The sample has list of URLs as a string. You can replace the URLs with your own and use a custom list adapter to display the image. You can also display the image name since you have the option of inflating the custom layout in your `ListView`.

The second solution is to use a Endless List Adapter from [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless). There is sample in the project which will help you understand and modify the same. If you still have any doubts regarding Endless List, post the same in Stack Overflow with tags `commonsware` and `android`.

Remember to provide permissions for writing images to external storage in manifest and also internet permission.